# how to send querystring as a get parameter swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, alamofire

I am using alamofire for api calling.

here is my code

```
func signup()
{
    let url = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
    let param =
    [
        "mobile_number" : "9999996586",
        "email_address" : "rakholiya@gmail.com",
        "password" : "123456",
        "api_key" : "4042328"
    ]
    request(.POST, url, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response:Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in

        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Now it's giving  response as unauthorised access. So I have to send the "apikey"in query string as get parameter and other data as POST so how can I do this?? I know this may be silly question. but I am new to developing so plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your apikey in url which will behave like get

```
let url = "www.google.com/signup.php?apikey=xyz" //apikey is your key and xyz is your value
```

And rest of your work will be same, don't need to change it.

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you because i'm able to open your link, most of the url are blocked. Thats why i cant help you, but i told you this one is the first n last solution if you wanna use both method GET & POST at same time.

Comment: @Raj i don't know how the back end developer handled the request.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass param at the end of the url string to send complete request to the server like following like.

```
let url = "www.yahoo.com/signup.php?apikey=abc"
```

rest of the parameter you can pass as same you have already done.

```
let param =
[
    "mobile_number" : "9999996586",
    "email_address" : "rakholiya@gmail.com",
    "password" : "123456"
]
request(.POST, url, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response:Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in

    print(response.result.value)
}
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: ohh ok..its same thing.. but sorry i haven't read your answer.. i have just read question and post my answer.